# Complexity of Medtronic respirator vs. DIY

Tags: medical-devices

Now that Medtronic has open sourced ([WIP](http://newsroom.medtronic.com/news-releases/news-release-details/medtronic-shares-ventilation-design-specifications-accelerate) reportedly for its completeness) the design of a ventilator, the following question to experts in medical engineering with specialization on lung ventilators.

What could be blocking obstacles, if any, for a typical DIY shop with say mid-range equipment to replicate such a device following these specs?

Comment: What is a “typical diy shop”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical DIY shop would fall over the electronics immediately.  This is more a piece of electronics than a mechanical device.  First of all, the shop would need the source of the chips which as far as I can tell aren't even referenced.  This is a set of assembly drawings, not complete product specifications. It tells you how to build a circuit board, but certainly not the processor at the heart of it. Second, the shop would need a software arm to write the software for the product, which is also not given.  What is given is a set of software *Requirements*, which is very different from software design specifications.

Maybe a manufacturer of similar devices could use this to aid their design and manufacturing process, but a DIY shop has no chance.

Comment: According to the licence document https://www.medtronic.com/content/dam/medtronic-com/global/Corporate/covid19/documents/permissive-license-open-ventilator.pdf Medtronic are distributing the software as part of the specification. Obviously, without it the whole exercise would just be a silly publicity stunt. (I haven't downloaded the spec itself)

Comment: are they distributing the integrated circuits as well?

Comment: from the circuits listed in the specs it looks like you woudn't need lithoraphic processes. Have a look.

Comment: agreed - there are indeed IC names seen in circuit plans like ST10F278 by ST Microelectronics. A DIY shop can't make them, never heard of lithography DIY shop for ICs.

Comment: Why all the hangup about "not being able to make an IC?" Everybody who designs and manufactures electronic products **buys** components. You don't manufacture your own copper wire and solder, either!

Comment: @alephzero the question was could a small DIY shop do it, which I took to be like building a model steam engine.